# Why logback.groovy is not taking Config objects although the externalization is written in application.yml in grails?

Tags: grails, logback

I have searched this scenario for many times and found out that, grails applicationcontext is not available at the time logback.groovy is loaded. That makes sense but in the application.yml I have written :

```
logging:
config: ../logback.groovy
```

This is to externalize my logback.groovy file. So when I run my application my logback.groovy is loaded from external location rather than default. But still when I use `Holders.config` in logback.groovy it is null.

So my question is being loaded from the settings in applicationcontext why applicationcontext is not available in logback.groovy.

I hope I am somewhat clear about my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

logging.config accepts a spring resource pattern. so you can specify a classpath resource or a file system resource etc.

Example

```
environments:
  production:
    logging: #Logback config for production
       config: file:/<path-to-logback-config.groovy>
```

**Note**: its **`file:/<path-to-logback-config.groovy>`**

See the example here [How to externalize logback configuration](http://nimavat.me/code-snippets/external-logback-configuration)

Comment: I am not having any problems in externalizing the file, my issue is the file being externalized through application.yml it is not taking the application context object. How applicationContext is not available if the logback file is loaded with the information provided in application.yml?

Comment: I guess GrailsApplicationPostProcessor has not run by the time logback.groovy is loaded, so Holders.config would not have been set, try putting a break point in GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.loadApplicationConfig